# Debian IPv6 routing

Tags: networking, configuration, routing, ipv6, iproute

I'm need to add gateway from server dashboard page to routing list for accessing IPv6 from internet and I try to do this using `ip -6 route add default via <gateway ipv6>` but i geted this error **RTNETLINK answers: No route to host**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is trying to tell you: "I cannot reach that gateway address through any IPv6 networks I'm connected to." Is the gateway IPv6 address really within the address range of one of the IPv6 networks you're connected to?

Ideally, an IPv6 router should be announcing itself using ICMPv6 router advisory messages, so that it could be discovered automatically and you should not have to configure it manually at all.

Comment: ok, I got it. The question is appeared because i'm create instance on scaleway with ipv6, but something going wrong and in support they adviced setup it manualy with command in my question

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 gateway is normally discovered automatically thanks to the Neighbor Discovery Protocol AKA NDP. It works through ICMPv6 messages.

You should make sure that netfilter is not blocking those. Example in ip6tables-save format:

```
-A INPUT -i wanif -p icmpv6 -s fe80::/10 -d fe80::/10 -j ACCEPT
```

While you are at it, you probably also want to get an IPv6 address from yout internet access provider. If you need to allow DHCPv6 with Prefix Delegation, make sure that you have:

```
-A INPUT -i wanif -p udp -s fe80::/10 -d fe80::/10 -m state --state NEW --dport 546 --sport 547 -j ACCEPT
```